# Trace in correlations to compute Wigner transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, correlation-functions, trace, wigner-transform

In the derivation of Wigner-transformed quantum time correlation functions, the following identity is used (in the case of a one-dimensional particle, for simplicity):
\begin{align}
C(t) &\equiv \text{tr}\{\hat \rho \hat A \hat B(t) \}=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm d q <q|\rho \hat A \hat B(t) |q> = \\
&=\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm d q \; \int_{\mathbb R}\mathrm d \Delta <q+\Delta/2|\hat \rho \hat A |q-\Delta/2><q-\Delta/2| \hat B(t) |q+\Delta/2>.
\end{align}
I would argue that the following decompositions of the identity are used 
to write the previous expression:
\begin{align}
I = \int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm d q \; \int_{\mathbb R}\mathrm d \Delta |q\pm \Delta/2><q\pm\Delta/2|.
\end{align}
Are these expansions corrects? If so, how can I use them to prove the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your resolution of the identity is unsound, since you are integrating over two variables, when the compete set of states you are inserting is indexed by only one. Do you understand how to switch to "light cone" variables?

$$
\int \! \!  d q ~~  \langle q |\hat \rho \hat A  \hat B(t) |q\rangle = \int \! \!  d q ~ d\Delta ~~  \langle q |\hat \rho \hat A |\Delta \rangle \langle \Delta | \hat B(t) |q\rangle . 
$$

Now change variables to 
$$
(q,\Delta ) \mapsto (q+\Delta/2, q-\Delta/2),
$$ 
with unit Jacobian.

Comment: That sounds way more solid to me, thanks

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Just curious, why center of mass transformation is called Light cone?

Comment: @Sunyam Oh, just cultural... or right-left moving waves... Just names.